# Copying rows from a .txt file and transfer them into a batch file

Tags: c#, web-services, batch-file, wsdl

I have a .txt file like this

*Text1

Text2

Service1.wsdl

Sercice2.wsdl

NoService1.txt

NoService2.txt

Service3.txt

....*

Now I want to copy the names from every existing Service (Service1.wsdl, Service2.wsdl,...) into a `string` inside C#, so that I can work with them later.

I need something in C# like

"get every name before ".wsdl" from the .txt file and copy them into a string so I can work with them in a loop inside C#"

Comment: What have you done so far? Any efforts?

Comment: Please try something and if you encountered any errors, we are here to help.

Comment: thanks a lot! I already wrote some code

Comment: string[] zeilenDerTXT =   System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\AutomatisierteWebServiceVeroeffentlichung\VonDerDiscoGefundeneWSDLDateien\AlleEingelesenenWSDLDateien.txt");  
            string[] nurDieZeilenDerTXTMitWSDL;  
            foreach (string line in zeilenDerTXT)  
            {    
                if (line.Contains(".wsdl"))  
                {  
                    nurDieZeilenDerTXTMitWSDL.  
                }  
            }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it :)

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("myTXTWithAllLines").Where(s => s.Contains("wsdl")).ToArray();  
File.WriteAllLines("MyTXTWithOnlyWSDLLines", lines);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to write code for you, because I'm not able to see if you have done anything so far.

You could read the *.txt* with **File.ReadAllLines**.

Then check each element(each row is an element in this new array) if it contains the `.wsdl`.
And then you can copy that element and work with it.